# Conditional dataframe splitting and sorting

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like below first few entries

df:

```
idx no                  surity      name        percentage  result
0   0.29999999999999993 0.974185    computer    0.84        1
1   0.18000000000000016 1.0         vegetables  1.14        1
2   0.27                1.0         electronics 1.32        1
3   0.17999999999999994 0.999655    books       1.59        0
4   0.8399889999999997  0.99992     fruits      1.770008    2
```

I want to export like this below in two different ways as json, where the file is single export, but, at first as initial, instead of name are values of result, and in later final there is no such change only first four columns.

```
"initial":[
 {
        "no":0.3,
        "surity":"null",
        "name":"1",
        "percentage":"0.84",
    },
    {
        "no":0.18,
        "surity":"null",
        "name":"1",
        "percentage":"1.14",
    },
    {
        "no":0.27,
        "surity":"null",
        "name":"1",
        "percentage":"1.32",
    },
    {
        "no":0.18,
        "surity":"null",
        "name":"0",
        "percentage":"1.59",
    },
    {
        "no":0.83999,
        "surity":"null",
        "name":"2",
        "percentage":"1.770007",
    }
]
"final":
[
 {
        "no":0.3,
        "surity":"0.973225",
        "name":"computer",
        "percentage":"0.84",
    },
    {
        "no":0.18,
        "surity":"1.0",
        "name":"vegetables",
        "percentage":"1.14",
    },
    {
        "no":0.27,
        "surity":"1.0",
        "name":"electronics",
        "percentage":"1.32",
    },
    {
        "no":0.18,
        "surity":"0.999663",
        "name":"books",
        "percentage":"1.59",
    },
    {
        "no":0.83999,
        "surity":"0.99991",
        "name":"fruits",
        "percentage":"1.770007",
    }
]
```

Also, the second export, i want is like for initial, all the name values are same in sequence get summed at no and result as single entry as below shown :

```
"initial":[
 {
        "no":3.3,
        "surity":"null",
        "name":"1",
        "percentage":"0.84",
    },
    {
        "no":0.18,
        "surity":"null",
        "name":"0",
        "percentage":"1.59",
    },
    {
        "no":0.83999,
        "surity":"null",
        "name":"2",
        "percentage":"1.770007",
    }
]
"final":
[
 {
        "no":0.3,
        "surity":"0.973225",
        "name":"computer",
        "percentage":"0.84",
    },
    {
        "no":0.18,
        "surity":"1.0",
        "name":"vegetables",
        "percentage":"1.14",
    },
    {
        "no":0.27,
        "surity":"1.0",
        "name":"electronics",
        "percentage":"1.32",
    },
    {
        "no":0.18,
        "surity":"0.999663",
        "name":"books",
        "percentage":"1.59",
    },
    {
        "no":0.83999,
        "surity":"0.99991",
        "name":"fruits",
        "percentage":"1.770007",
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All about being systematic following your instructions

- `to_dict(orient="records")` provides what you want when DF is prepared
- `drop()` columns and `rename()` columns gets your first export
- using `groupby()` and `agg()` to get aggregates gets your second export

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""idx no  surity  name    percentage  result
0   0.29999999999999993 0.974185    computer    0.84    1
1   0.18000000000000016 1.0 vegetables  1.14    1
2   0.27    1.0 electronics 1.32    1
3   0.17999999999999994 0.999655    books   1.59    0
4   0.8399889999999997  0.99992 fruits  1.770008    2"""), sep="\s+", index_col=0)

df.no = df.no.round(4)

exp1 = {"initial":df
        .drop(columns="name")
        .rename(columns={"result":"name"})
        .assign(surity=np.nan)
        .to_dict(orient="records")
,"final":df.drop(columns="result").to_dict(orient="records")
}

exp2 = {"initial":df.groupby(["result"]).agg({"no":"first","percentage":"sum"}).reset_index()
 .rename(columns={"result":"name"}).assign(surity=np.nan).to_dict(orient="records")
 ,"final":df.groupby(["name"]).agg({"no":"first","percentage":"sum","surity":"first"}).reset_index().to_dict("records")
}
```

### exp1

```
{'initial': [{'no': 0.3, 'surity': nan, 'percentage': 0.84, 'name': 1},
  {'no': 0.18, 'surity': nan, 'percentage': 1.14, 'name': 1},
  {'no': 0.27, 'surity': nan, 'percentage': 1.32, 'name': 1},
  {'no': 0.18, 'surity': nan, 'percentage': 1.59, 'name': 0},
  {'no': 0.84, 'surity': nan, 'percentage': 1.770008, 'name': 2}],
 'final': [{'no': 0.3,
   'surity': 0.974185,
   'name': 'computer',
   'percentage': 0.84},
  {'no': 0.18, 'surity': 1.0, 'name': 'vegetables', 'percentage': 1.14},
  {'no': 0.27, 'surity': 1.0, 'name': 'electronics', 'percentage': 1.32},
  {'no': 0.18, 'surity': 0.999655, 'name': 'books', 'percentage': 1.59},
  {'no': 0.84, 'surity': 0.99992, 'name': 'fruits', 'percentage': 1.770008}]}
```

### exp2

```
{'initial': [{'name': 0, 'no': 0.18, 'percentage': 1.59, 'surity': nan},
  {'name': 1, 'no': 0.3, 'percentage': 3.3, 'surity': nan},
  {'name': 2, 'no': 0.84, 'percentage': 1.770008, 'surity': nan}],
 'final': [{'name': 'books',
   'no': 0.18,
   'percentage': 1.59,
   'surity': 0.999655},
  {'name': 'computer', 'no': 0.3, 'percentage': 0.84, 'surity': 0.974185},
  {'name': 'electronics', 'no': 0.27, 'percentage': 1.32, 'surity': 1.0},
  {'name': 'fruits', 'no': 0.84, 'percentage': 1.770008, 'surity': 0.99992},
  {'name': 'vegetables', 'no': 0.18, 'percentage': 1.14, 'surity': 1.0}]}
```

Comment: for exp1, surity needs to be null: and the exp2: no needs to add where same result is available. like where result is 1, it is added all three no and returned one value of no. and rest two has different values. then if the result value has again 1 value in sequence, there again it is added. This is to unite the similar result values in sequence

Comment: is your specification/requirement right?  In your example not all `surity` are null for `expr1` just some (`initial`).  get you spec 100% clear and it's simple.

Comment: for initial, surity will be exported then as null: I know only one value is 0 but I will switch all as "null"

Comment: for exp2, if the results are 1,1,1 than, no needs to add and I get exported for that, later are 0 and 2 values, and if after 1,1,1 are again in dataframe, those needs to add separately in that period of sequence.

Comment: use a much more formal specification language - honestly I have no idea now what you are trying to achieve.  your spec is aa strange mix of semantic and syntax structures,  rather then full separation

Comment: I have updated answer for `xpr1`.  `expr2` I do not know your filter, aggregation and projection logic in any stable way to suggest a solution

Comment: exp2 solution is wrong here, I have to group in the continued result number, if when change, than the sum is stopped, again if result number is repeated at any sequence, that needs to add up again at that place.